# A Puzzle Squared

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, steganography

For this puzzle, I have taken to paper. Apologies if its a bit hard to read...

The final answer will answer:

> **What can I call this puzzle?**

(Click for a larger picture)

[image: Letter Square]

Transcription (You will need the image itself for most of the puzzle though):

$\begin{array}\\\huge{\text{UCPN}}\\\huge\text{IWIE}\\\huge{\text{DZNV}}\\\huge{\text{SRFV}}\end{array}$

```
UCPN
IWIE
DZNV
SRFV
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that

> the letters are composed of bold lines and straight lines, but any wavy lines have strangely been ignored.

If we

> take the bold lines and wavy lines together, we get letter shapes - specifically, letter shapes *upside down*. These spell "THE KEY IS DOWNPOUR".

Finally,

> we can decode the right-side-up letters (helpfully transcribed for us) as a Vigenere cipher with key DOWNPOUR to get the name of the puzzle: it's a **ROTATIONAL RIDDLE**!

Edit from OP:

> Deusovi has got the puzzle write but there was one more step. The dots are underneath the letters  U, P, I, E, D and S. This forms the word **UPSIDE** and the dots and underneath giving **UPSIDE DOWN**. This tells you to look at the picture upside down giving the message Deusovi found...

Also here is an explained picture of the upside down characters if you are finding it hard to see:

> [image] [image]

Comment: Good! You’ve missed one more key bit though -  check the letters with dots and also look at the position of the dots. You’ve actually included the phrase in your answer without realising there was a clue for it :)